# If-statement inside Add() method?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to add each line of a textfile to different columns in a `listView`. However, I've run into a problem.

This is how I did a method:

```
public void OpenFile()
        {
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            openFileDialog.Filter = "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
            string line = "";
            int index = 0;
            if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
            using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(openFileDialog.FileName))
            {
                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    index++;
                    if (index == 1)
                        InvoiceNumbertxt.Text = line;
                    else if (index == 2)
                        InvoiceDatetxt.Text = line;
                    else if (index == 3)
                        DueDatetxt.Text = line;
                    else if (index == 4 || index == 5 || index == 6 || index == 7 || index == 8 || index == 9)
                        PersonInfolst.Items.Add(line);
                    else if (index == 10)
                    {
                        Items.Add(new ItemProperties 
                        {     
                            Item = line
                            if(index == 11)// <---- If-statement inside Add?
                            Description = line;


                        });
                        itemlst.ItemsSource = Items;
                    }
                    else
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
```

As you can see index is just a convenient flag (variable) to insert the lines in order, and not overlap multiple lines into the same control.

**The problem** I have is I want to check if index is a value *inside* the Add() method so that I can add the new textFile line to the same row but different column in the list.

**UPDATE:**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        ObservableCollection<ItemProperties> Items =
        new ObservableCollection<ItemProperties>();
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public ObservableCollection<ItemProperties> GameCollection
        {
            get
            {
                if (Items == null)
                {
                    Items = new ObservableCollection<ItemProperties>();
                }
                return Items;
            }
        } 

        private void btnOpenFile_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFile();
        }

        public void OpenFile()
        {
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            openFileDialog.Filter = "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
            string line = "";
            int index = 0;
            if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
            using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(openFileDialog.FileName))
            {
                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    index++;
                    if (index == 1)
                        InvoiceNumbertxt.Text = line;
                    else if (index == 2)
                        InvoiceDatetxt.Text = line;
                    else if (index == 3)
                        DueDatetxt.Text = line;
                    else if (index == 4 || index == 5 || index == 6 || index == 7 || index == 8 || index == 9)
                        PersonInfolst.Items.Add(line);
                    else if (index == 10)
                    {
                        Items.Add(new ItemProperties { Item = line });
                        itemlst.ItemsSource = Items;
                    }
                    else if (index == 11)
                    {
                        //??

                    }
                    else
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        private void btnOpenImage_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog openfile = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
            openfile.DefaultExt = "*.jpg";
            openfile.Filter = "Image Files|*.jpg";
            Nullable<bool> result = openfile.ShowDialog();
            if (result == true)
            {
                imagefile.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(openfile.FileName));
            }
        }

        public class ItemProperties
        {
            public string Item { get; set; }
            public string Description { get; set; }
            public string Quantity { get; set; }
            public string UnitPrice { get; set; }
            public string Tax { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try the ternary operator `Description = (index == 11) ? line : ""`

Comment: this code will actually never run... because index will always be 10 when entering if inex==10 statement

Comment: One note: in this example, `if(index == 11)` is never true, because you only do the add if `index == 10`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ternary operator to perform an inline conditional check and set the value

```
Description = (index == 11) ? line : "";
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it **not** in the Add()-Method but inside of the object initializer of `ItemProperties`. It is not possible there!

The best solution is to write an extra Add method and create the new `ItemProperties` object there.

```
private MyAdd(string line, int index)
{
   if(index == 11)
      Items.Add(new ItemProperties {Item = line, Description = "line11"});
   else
      Items.Add(new ItemProperties {Item = line, Description = "other"});
}
```

and then

```
else if (index == 10)
{
    MyAdd(line, index);
    itemlst.ItemsSource = Items;
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should consider using `switch`, because it looks an ideal use in this case. Multiple ifs aren't really great for your needs.

Secondly, you can use simple ternary operator on assigning the value, some like this:

```
Description = id == 11 ? line : null;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
else if (index == 10)
{
    Items.Add(new ItemProperties{Item = line});
     itemlst.ItemsSource = Items;
}
else if (index == 11)
{
     Description = line;
}
```

forget the loop

```
InvoiceNumbertxt.Text = sr.ReadLine();
InvoiceDatetxt.Text = sr.ReadLine();
...
Items.Add(new ItemProperties 
                        {     
                            Item = sr.ReadLine();
                            Description = sr.ReadLine();
                        });
```

Comment: I can't access `Description` like that. But I like your idea. Please check my updated question on how my class looks like

Comment: `Description` is in a class